# Framer-Motion - How to animate multiple cards

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

TL;DR - How to animate multiple cards with react and framer-motion?

Hi,

I doubt I am the first one to ask this (but I can't seem to find a solid answer anywhere), but I am struggling to recreate the [Card Animation from the Framer-Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=adwords&utm_campaign=TW-WW-All-GS-UA-Traffic-20190326-Brand.Bmm_&gclid=CjwKCAjwrdmhBhBBEiwA4Hx5g9oUE_-tSaUxfbwkt1fBklkYlcPodheigJviYgD1gzlxVd9g4RnXsRoCXu4QAvD_BwE).

[image: Framer-Motion card animation]

I am looking to recreate the click-expand and focus effect I see on the page, but I can only seems to get it to work for 1 card. The below code only renders the cards but I can't seem to give them animation and I am definitely stuck on what to do next (i.e. I've definitely missed something on how to control the card state with react).

[image: Rendered version using given code snip]

```
const JobsPage = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)
  
  const cards = [{
    id: 1,
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. A, minima?',
    title: 'Card 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    title: 'Card 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    title: 'Card 3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    title: 'Card 4'
  }]
  return (
      <div class="">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold flex justify-center">
          Jobs
        </h2>
        {/* Jobs Tab */}
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 bg-green-300 justify-between p-4 space-x-2">
          {cards.map(card => (
            <motion.div layoutId={card.id} class="bg-white p-2" onClick={() => setSelectedId(card.id)}>
              <motion.h2>{card.title}</motion.h2>
              <motion.h5>{card.subtitle}</motion.h5>
            </motion.div>
          ))}

          <AnimatePresence>
            {selectedId && (
              <motion.div layoutId={selectedId}>
                {/* <motion.h5>{cards.subtitle}</motion.h5>
                <motion.h2>{cards.title}</motion.h2> */}
                <motion.button onClick={() => setSelectedId(null)} />
              </motion.div>
            )}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this article that recreated a similar (but with more features) version of what you're looking for:

https://framermotionplayground.com/tutorial/layout-cards

Only posting this as an answer because I can't comment lol. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Decided to create a Code Sandbox and give a working solution to this problem.
Code Sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-sid-c975nw

The relevant code/component is as follows:

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

const App = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState('');
  const items = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Card 1',
      subtitle: 'Information 1',
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Card 2',
      subtitle: 'Information 2',
      description: 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Card 3',
      subtitle: 'Information 3',
      description:
        'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.',
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      title: 'Card 4',
      subtitle: 'Information 4',
      description:
        'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <motion.div className="bg-purple-600 flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <motion.div
            className={`card bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md cursor-pointer transform transition-transform duration-500 hover:scale-105 ${
              selectedId === item.id ? 'card-selected' : ''
            }`}
            layoutId={`card-container-${item.id}`}
            onClick={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
            key={item.id}
            initial={{ scale: 1 }}
            animate={{ scale: selectedId === item.id ? 1.1 : 1 }} // Increase scale on selected card
            transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
          >
            <div className="card-content">
              <motion.h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-2 text-purple-600">{item.title}</motion.h2>
              <motion.h5 className="text-sm font-bold mb-1 text-gray-700">{item.subtitle}</motion.h5>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <AnimatePresence>
        {selectedId && (
          <motion.div
            className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 flex items-center justify-center"
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          >
            {items.map((item) => (
              item.id === selectedId && (
                <motion.div
                  className="bg-white rounded-lg p-4 shadow-md max-w-lg mx-auto"
                  layoutId={`card-container-${item.id}`}
                  key={item.id}
                  initial={{ scale: 0.8, opacity: 0 }}
                  animate={{ scale: 1, opacity: 1 }}
                  exit={{ scale: 0.8, opacity: 0 }}
                >
                  <motion.div className="relative">
                    <motion.button
                      className="absolute top-2 right-2 py-1 px-2 text-center text-white bg-red-500 rounded-full"
                      onClick={() => setSelectedId('')}
                    >
                      Close
                    </motion.button>
                    <motion.h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-2 text-purple-600">{item.title}</motion.h2>
                    <motion.h5 className="text-sm font-bold mb-1 text-gray-700">{item.subtitle}</motion.h5>
                    <motion.p className="text-md text-gray-700 mb-4">{item.description}</motion.p>
                    <motion.p
                      className="text-md text-gray-700"
                      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    >
                      Additional content can go here!
                    </motion.p>
                  </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
              )
            ))}
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34576956)

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike Hence why I said I only posted it as an answer because I can't comment, I figured providing a resource in an incorrect manner was better than not providing it at all.